# Python: convert procedural script to class and object (oop) style

Tags: python, oop

I am still learning to code in python and I am struggling to code object-oriented way. I have written a code using pytessarct library and with the extracted words I have tried to make a simple detector by using keywords as a filter. I want to redo it in class and object format strictly as a learning exercise. Will be highly grateful if anybody can extend any help. Thank you

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe' 
import os
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import ImageFilter
import re 
img_path = 'C:/Users/RAJ/realtest/'

for i in os.listdir(img_path):
  images=Image.open(img_path+'//'+i)
  plt.imshow(images)
  plt.show()
  images_new=images.convert('LA')
  im_SHARPEN2 = images_new.filter(filter=ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
  extract = pytesseract.image_to_string(im_SHARPEN2, lang = 'eng')
  extract2 = pytesseract.image_to_string(images_new,lang = 'eng')
  final= extract+extract2  
  x = re.search(r"INCOME|TAX|Account|GOVT.", final,re.M|re.I)
  y = re.search(r"GOVERNMENT|DOB|Male|Female.", final,re.M|re.I)
if x == None and y== None:
    print('Not a pan card or adhaar card')
elif type(x)== re.Match:
    print('This is a pan card')
else:
    print('adhaar card detected')
```

Comment: This question might be a better fit for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you want the code indentation to stay clean, copy-paste your code, select it and press ctrl+K.

Comment: As you said this was just an exercise for you, but I highly recommend to read [this](https://eev.ee/blog/2013/03/03/the-controller-pattern-is-awful-and-other-oo-heresy/). A class with just the constructor and one method should be just a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe' 
import os
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import ImageFilter
import re 

class is_pan_card():
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.img_path = path
        
        for i in os.listdir(self.img_path):
            images=Image.open(self.img_path+'//'+i)
            plt.imshow(images)
            plt.show()
            images_new=images.convert('LA')
            im_SHARPEN2 = images_new.filter(filter=ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
            extract = pytesseract.image_to_string(im_SHARPEN2, lang = 'eng')
            extract2 = pytesseract.image_to_string(images_new,lang = 'eng')
            final= extract+extract2  
            x = re.search(r"INCOME|TAX|Account|GOVT.", final,re.M|re.I)
            y = re.search(r"GOVERNMENT|DOB|Male|Female.", final,re.M|re.I)
        if x == None and y== None:
            print('Not a pan card or adhaar card')
        elif type(x)== re.Match:
            print('This is a pan card')
        else:
            print('adhaar card detected')

is_pan =is_pan_card('C:/Users/RAJ/realtest/')
```

Comment: This is working fine thank you so much for this :)